# Converting sas numeric variable type in dataset to character type

Tags: sas, type-conversion, character, numeric

I'm importing a csv to a sas dataset with this code:

```
PROC IMPORT
     DATAFILE  = '/folders/myshortcuts/SASsoftware_rialto_2015/providence_med_claims_15.csv'
     OUT  = medical
     DBMS=DLM REPLACE;
     DELIMITER='|';
     getnames=yes;
run;
```

For the subsequent code it wants one of the fields called DIAGNOSIS_VERSION_CODE in this dataset to be a character type rather than numeric type which is the default. How can I change that default in the above code or convert the field in the dataset?

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
contents data=medical;
      modify medical;
         format  DIAGNOSIS_VERSION_CODE $CHAR8.;
   contents data=medical;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PROC DATASETS to change a variable's definition or values. You will need to create a new dataset. You can use the RENAME statement to make the new variable have the name of the old one.

```
data new_medical;
  set medical ;
  new_diagnosis_version_code = put(diagnosis_version_code,Z8.);
  rename diagnosis_version_code=old_diagnosis_version_code 
         new_diagnosis_version_code=diagnosis_version_code
  ;
run;
```

To prevent this in the future you should write your own data step to read the data instead of asking PROC IMPORT to guess what data you have. Then you have control over how the variables are created.